# Section title format

Tags: sectioning, numbering, titlesec

Can someone explain to me, how one can make a section look like this [image] and this [image]
I'm really having trouble with doing this, and I'm not sure if I should even use titlesec or titleformat, especially not for the picture with a big 1 on the right. I would really like to know how to accomplish picture 2. Anyone that can help me? Would be much appreciated. This is of course in LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should use `titlesec`. As to `\titleformat`,  it's a command from titlesec, not a package. Do you want this for a section, not a chapter? Which class will you use?

Comment: I would like to make a section like the first picture and also a section like the second picture. I usually don't write chapters.

Comment: You wrote, "I usually don't write chapters." You seem to want to have it both ways: Give your readers a clear visual impression that a chapter-type header is being encountered, yet simultaneously not want to use any chapter-related typesetting machinery. Why this disconnect? The difference between a chapter-level header and a section-level header is not just semantic.

Comment: Well I didn't realise that was a chapter, i thought this was a section because why shouldn't it be? I mean, it says one, and then the name of the section directly followed by 1.1 after. I didn't know, but it honestly wasn't my point to confuse you if that's the case.

Comment: You didn't confuse *me*. What you're running the risk of doing here is to *confuse your readers*, by applying a document division style that's traditionally reserved for "major" subdivision headers (chapters and parts) to a "minor" subdivision header (such as section, subsection, etc). A document that employs a visually inappropriate and confusing style runs the risk of being viewed by readers either as baroque and overly ornate or (worse) as distracting and even risible. Naturally, it's *your* document -- if you don't mind incurring this risk, go right ahead and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two example solutions, adapted from a code for `\chapter`. With this type of layout, I had to change the class of `\section`  so that a new section starts a newpage, and begins at top of page:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsproc

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage[]{titlesec}%

\titleclass{\section}{top}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
{\filleft\bfseries}
{\fontsize{72}{75}\selectfont\color{SlateGray3}\thesection}
{8ex}
{\LARGE}%
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{-8ex}{12ex}

\begin{document}

\section {The History of the Seven Families}%

           In former days – that is to say, once upon a time, there lived in the Land of Gramblamble, Seven Families. They lived by the side of the great Lake Pipple-popple (one of the Seven Families, indeed, lived in the Lake), and on the outskirts of the City of Tosh, which, excepting when it was quite dark, they could see plainly. The names of all these places you have probably heard of, and you have only not to look in your Geography books to find out all about them.

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsproc

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage[]{titlesec}%

\titleclass{\section}{top}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
{\filleft\bfseries}
{\Huge\color{SlateGray3}\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\thesection}\enspace \titlerule[1pt]}
{6ex}
{\LARGE}[\vspace{4.5ex}{\color{SlateGray3}\titlerule[1pt]}]%
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{-6ex}{12ex}

\begin{document}

\section {The History of the Seven Families}%

           In former days – that is to say, once upon a time, there lived in the Land of Gramblamble, Seven Families. They lived by the side of the great Lake Pipple-popple (one of the Seven Families, indeed, lived in the Lake), and on the outskirts of the City of Tosh, which, excepting when it was quite dark, they could see plainly. The names of all these places you have probably heard of, and you have only not to look in your Geography books to find out all about them.

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:*

The formatting of the toc title can be different from the above using `\titleformat`, with the `numberless` key, since table of contents, references, &c., are implemented as unnumbered sections in the article class. Just add this code to your preamble:

```
\titleformat{name = \section, numberless}[block]
{\filright}
{}
{0pt}
{\huge\textbf}%
\titlespacing*{name = \section, numberless}{0pt}{-4ex}{12ex}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to point out explicitly that what you've done is to transfer the machinery that's generally reserved for part- and chapter-level headers to section-level headers. The difference isn't just semantic: Readers will likely be either confused or amused by the mixing and (mis)matching of visual and aesthetic metaphors...

Comment: Thanks, Bernard! Though, is it possible for the Table of Contents text that says 'Contents' to be not on the right but on the left? Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Cazo: Please accept Bernard's solution, not just say `Thank you`

Comment: @Mico: I indeed started from a code of mine for chapters, and I've added this detail. I've already warned the O.P. that sections had to start on a new page with such layouts.

Comment: @Cazo: I've added another formatting for unnumbered sections. Please see if it's OK for you.